# How to create ASP.NET websocket .ashx file's URL?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, websocket

I am a newbie of Websocket. I have created a ASP.NET Web project in Visual Studio named CAPWebSocketProject. Inside this project there is a .ashx file named CPWebSocket.ashx. Inside this ashx file, there are c# codes. Here are the codes:

```
 public class CPWebSocket : IHttpHandler
 {
    public long fnGetTerminalInfo()
    {
        string strCom = "COM4"; // hard coded for testing 

        string strGetTerminalInfoCommand = "C900";
        <XXXX> clsTerminal = new <XXXX>();


        long lgPortStat = clsTerminal.SendCommand(strCom, strGetTerminalInfoCommand);

        return lgPortStat;
    }
 }
```

Now, my question is how to create the websocket CPWebSocket.ashx file's URL so I can access from a browser?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think .ashx is websocket, you need to inherit from `WebSocketService` then you need to create object of `websocket` in javascript and give it the url of the `websocket` and the key want to listen to it, here's an example:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1063910/WebSocket-Server-in-Csharp

Comment: sorry, I have just changed the question I asked. Please refer back to the question.

Comment: @Antoni I think with .ashx or not, it's all about creating object of `WebSocketService` and run it with webserver, please refer to the article I mentioned.